# my form field doesn't appear at html file

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to fix this problem... I made a simple post form with forms.py but it doesn't show up at the HTML file. I searched at google but I still don't know how to fix it

## views.py

```py
from django.shortcuts import render
from contact.forms import contactForm

def contact(request):
    form = contactForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        return request.POST
    context = locals()
    template = 'contact.html'
    return render(request, 'contact/contact.html')
```

## contact.html

```html
{% block content %}
<h1>
    Contact doesn't appears..
</h1>
<form method = "POST">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
<input type = "submit" value = "submit form" class = 'btn btn-default' />
</form>
{% endblock %}
```

## forms.py

```py
from django import forms
from django.shortcuts import render

class contactForm(forms.Form):
    name = forms.CharField(required = False, max_length = 100, help_text='100 characters max.')
    email = forms.EmailField(required = True)
    comment = forms.CharField(required = True, widget = forms.Textarea)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass in the objects you want in the `render` function.

```
def contact(request):
    ...
    context = {'form': form}
    return render(request, 'news/year_archive.html', context)
```

As you can see you are passing the dictionary labeled `context` inside the render which should now be able to be accessed by your template.

[Django view example](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/intro/overview/#write-your-views)